# Javascript object variable?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS structure:

```
var master = {
    one: 'this is text',
    two: [
        {
            child: '#mydiv'
            child_two: ''
        },
        {
            child: '#mydiv'
            child_two: ''
        },
    ]
};
```

Is it possible to make `child_two` be equal to the `child` value?

Something like this: `master.two.child` = `'#mydiv'`

Comment: First off, the JS structure you show is not legal javascript.  Is `two` supposed to be an object, NOT an array?

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have to do it in two steps, like this:

```js
var master = {
    one: 'this is text',
    two: {
        child: '#mydiv'
    }
};
master.two.child_two = master.two.child;

alert(JSON.stringify(master, null, 4));
```

Or alternatively, you could define a variable ahead of time for the identical value, like so:

```
var myDivSelector = '#mydiv';
var master = {
    one: 'this is text',
    two: {
        child: myDivSelector,
        child_two: myDivSelector
    }
};
```